# Initializing swift class in objective c project causes infinite loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm trying to add a color picker in my add and I use this https://github.com/gizmosachin/ColorSlider library which is only written in swift and I use objective-c. I have followed this guide [How to call Objective-C code from Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift) on how to add swift libraries in objective-c projects. I'm 99% sure that I have properly configured xcode because I can import the swift library and run my app without an error, it's only when I try to instantiate the swift class that the app crashes and I see that the init method for the swift class is called infinitely. The source code for the library is one file and listed for reference just in case (https://github.com/gizmosachin/ColorSlider/blob/master/Source/ColorSlider.swift)

Here is one of the init methods (the other inits are overrides)

```
// MARK: Initializers
convenience init() {
    println("hi there swift")
    self.init()
    backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}
```

in my log I see "hi there swift" print out many times. This is how I initiate the swift class

```
ColorSlider *colorSlider = [[ColorSlider alloc] init];
```

I know that the function containing the line of code above is only being called once because I used NSLog(@"output") to see how many times this shows up and the output looks like this

```
output
hi there swift
hi there swift
hi there swift
hi there swift
hi there swift
etc...to infinity or until app crashes
```

Am I instantiating the swift class correctly? I'm not sure why the swift class's init method is called infinitely

----**UPDATE**-----

It looks as if the init methods below also use super.init?
[image]

Comment: Try remove self.init() or replace with init(frame: CGRect) or init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in Objective-C a class can have convenience (secondary) initializers and designated (primary) initializers.

The path of code execution should be:

1. A convenience initializer should call a designated initializer with `self.designatedInit()`.
2. A designated initializer should call a super's designated initializer with `super.designatedInit()`.

In your code, `init()` is a convenience initializer (`convenience init()`). calling `self.init()` would lead to an infinite loop, because this is the actually running function itself as Dan said.

If you change it to `super.init()` a convenience initializer is calling a super's initializer, what is illegal because of the above rule #1.

What to do?

1. Check, whether `init()` is really a convenience initializer.
2. If so, call `self.designatedInit()` instead of `self.init()`.
3. If not so, change the classification of `init()` and call `super.init()` (or whatever is the designated initializer of the super class.

Comment: So I ended up just deleting convenience init and now I can call the color slider since trying to call self.designatedInit caused another error, not sure what the repercussions are but since the only line in convenience init is setting the background color it should be fine. But thanks for your in depth explanation of designated and convenience init

Answer (score 2):

Remove self.init. The method is calling itself.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I tried changing self to super but I get a "Convenience initializer for 'ColorSlider' must delegate (with 'self.init') rather than chaining to a superclass initializer (with 'super init')", I'm not too familiar with swift but I'm going to look more into swift's docs, but what was the reasoning behind changing self to super? going to update question with screenshot of error. Sorry if I made a dumb mistake :/

Comment: Was assuming that your class was a subclass. In your case you don't need to call self.init(). What is happening is that your init() is recursively calling itself. Not even sure that you need to declare this as convenience. -- learning Swift myself right now:)